# Azure Machine Learning compute instance : Static IP address?

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, static-ip-address, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a SQL Server database which is accessible only by whitelisting IP addresses. I would like to use an Azure Machine Learning compute instance to run some python code to query the database using the `pyodbc` library.

Does a compute instance in Azure Machine Learning have a static IP address ?
If yes, can I safely provide this address to be whitelisted or is there a risk that it might change through time ?

Thank you very much.